# Django Dropbox storage

Tags: python, django, heroku, dropbox

i am trying to use django-storages with dropbox.
I did everything like in docs:

```
set DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.dropbox.DropBoxStorage',

DROPBOX_OAUTH2_TOKEN = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'
DROPBOX_ROOT_PATH = 'media'
```

But when I'm trying to upload images on heroku, i got an error in logs:

```
TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got
class'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'
```

full traceback:

> 2017-08-23T09:11:48.956735+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-08-23 12:11:48,874] exception: ERROR - Internal Server Error: /en/create/
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956748+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956749+00:00 app[web.1]: File /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956750+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956751+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956752+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956752+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956753+00:00 app[web.1]: response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956754+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956754+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956755+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956756+00:00 app[web.1]: return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956756+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 217, in post
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956757+00:00 app[web.1]: return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956760+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 183, in post
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956760+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.form_valid(form)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956761+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/articles/views.py", line 255, in form_valid
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956762+00:00 app[web.1]:     articleimages.save()
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956762+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 649, in save
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956763+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.save_existing_objects(commit) + self.save_new_objects(commit)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956763+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 783, in save_new_objects
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956763+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.new_objects.append(self.save_new(form, commit=commit))
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956764+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 932, in save_new
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956767+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 836, in save_base
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956767+00:00 app[web.1]:     updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956768+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 922, in _save_table
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956765+00:00 app[web.1]:     obj.save()
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956765+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 806, in save
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956766+00:00 app[web.1]:     force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956772+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1098, in execute_sql
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956769+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 961, in _do_insert
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956770+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956769+00:00 app[web.1]:     using=using, raw=raw)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956770+00:00 app[web.1]:     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956771+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1061, in _insert
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956772+00:00 app[web.1]:     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956768+00:00 app[web.1]:     result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956774+00:00 app[web.1]:     for obj in self.query.objs
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956773+00:00 app[web.1]:     for sql, params in self.as_sql():
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956773+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1051, in as_sql
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956774+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1051, in 
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956776+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1050, in 
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956775+00:00 app[web.1]:     for obj in self.query.objs
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956776+00:00 app[web.1]:     [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956777+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1000, in pre_save_val
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956779+00:00 app[web.1]:     file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956779+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 95, in save
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956780+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 54, in save
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956787+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/storages/backends/dropbox.py", line 111, in _save
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956786+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._save(name, content)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956780+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956777+00:00 app[web.1]:     return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956789+00:00 app[web.1]:     f,
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956778+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 297, in pre_save
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956790+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 234, in request
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956790+00:00 app[web.1]:     timeout=timeout)
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956791+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 325, in request_json_string_with_retry
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956788+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.client.files_upload(content, self._full_path(name))
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956788+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dropbox/base.py", line 1267, in files_upload
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956792+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 369, in request_json_string
>       2017-08-23T09:11:48.956794+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>

Comment: If you want help debugging, you should post the full traceback, not just the exception.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have hit a bug in the `DropBoxStorage` backend. See [issue 378](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/378) for example. The issue has been fixed but there hasn't been a release since. You could try installing the master branch to see if it works.